# Cost of Australian Expression of Interest?

Tags: australia

I am looking at different working visas for Australia and the current cost of a skilled working visa is quite expensive and timely with no guarantee that you will be given one.

I have been looking into the expression of interest and they will invite you to make a visa application if you are successful. However, I can't find any information on how much this costs?

Also, as a sub question:

Can you apply for other types of visas whilst waiting? For example, if you have found a job where someone will sponsor you? Or if you wanted to apply for a working holiday visa?

Comment: I think it is free to the "applicant" but completing the application seems to require certification evidence which cannot be obtained gratis.

Comment: @pnuts - thanks for this! Do you know about my second question?

Comment: As a Q&A site I believe you should only post one question at a time. I doubt there is anything stopping you from posting more Qs (some users may be rate limited) and providing links there, if appropriate, to add background (but each should 'stand alone' regardless). Yes, I think you can in all three cases.

Comment: In the body I would agree there is scope to differ regarding what the "this" is in *what this costs* but I think the Title settles such ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Expression of interest is free... It costs to get to it though... let me explain:

You get Expression of interest(EOI) when you apply to [SkillSelect](https://skillselect.gov.au/) with your notarized references and diploma and report form agency (in my case ACS)...

EOI is a farther step in the process of applying to get visa... where once you know (hope) you have sufficient points from your assessor (ACS), then you go to [SkillSelect](https://skillselect.gov.au/) and give them you IELTS reference, ACS reference, all the other point scoring details (this is you showing EOI), and then you get your points report based on what you have submitted (see bellow)

[image]

you then wait for email that asks you to apply for visa where you have to submit everything again...

And this is where it will [actually will COST you](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/190-#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ProductQuestionsPanel_VisaDetailsPageTrimmingControl3)... 2k+ and they can give you different points [and you cannot appeal](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10326/under-which-clause-can-i-get-back-australian-visa-application-fee-if-skillselect#answer-10974)...

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the process. Do we need to provide and ACS Reference (what would that be? is there any cost for it? how long does it take to get it?) for submitting EOI?
I used to think ACS assessment comes after EOI and after being invited. Will you please explain the order of cost payments?

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari just don't do it, your name sounds Indian you might want to look for less racist country https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violence_against_Indians_in_Australia_controversy ,if you still want to understand how it works try reading answer again...

Comment: I'm actually Iranian, and I know Australia is not a racist country. My brother's been living there for a decade now. Look, quoting your sentence, you said "...then you go to SkillSelect and give them you IELTS reference, ACS reference...". Do you mean ACS assessment comes before EOI? I thought EOI does not need any proofs, and you need to give proofs once invited, am I wrong?